# .push() not pushing into array with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

im trying to map through users in a database and .push() each of them into an array so i cant send it as a response to the client but its returning an empty object im not sure if the data has been pushed  and its returning before the array is updated?

```
export const getFollowers = async (req,res) => {
                console.log(req.body)
                const profilename=req.body.profilename
                const followingarray = []
              
                try{
             await userModel.find({username:profilename},async (err,data)=> {
                const following = data[0].following
         
              
                following.map(async(whoimFollowing)=>{
                  
                  const users_found = await userModel.findOne({ username: whoimFollowing }).then(
                   
                    (data)=> {   
                        console.log(data)
                        followingarray.push(data)})
                 
               
                 
                
            })
           await res.status(208).json(followingarray)
        })
            
                }catch(e){
                   
                }
            }
```

Comment: It's not the problem, but you're [misusing `map`](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/) *(post on my blog)*. If you're not using the array `map` creates, don't use `map`, use a loop or `forEach`.

Comment: See the linked question's answers. Mongoose freezes the objects it gives you (including arrays). If you want to modify the object in MongoDB, you need to use the API to do that. If you just want to modify it for use in your code and not in the DB, your have to copy it and then modify and use the copy.

Comment: i have tried that but i am having problems could you give an example?

Comment: If you search for "copy an object" and "copy an array," you'll find lots and lots of examples and deatils.